# How to listen BOTH expand/collapse events of SearchView which is NOT a MenuItem?

Tags: android

The `SearchView` is a direct child of a horizontal `RelativeLayout` title bar. When it's a `MenuItem`, we have `setOnActionExpandListener`. But it's not a `MenuItem` now. How do I listen *both* expand/collapse events of the `SearchView`?

---

Edit:

1) Malwinder's `SearchView.OnCloseListener` only triggers for collapse events, but not for expand events.

2) [`CollapsibleActionView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/CollapsibleActionView.html) is a [`MenuItem`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html)-related  or "action view"-related interface, and is only called when the associated view serves as a `MenuItem` action view.

Answer (score 3):

```
SearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus){
                //just expanded, do something...
            }else {
                //just collapsed, do something...
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [SearchView.OnCloseListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnCloseListener.html)

```
mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onClose()
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "mSearchView on close ");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Edit:** `SearchView` implements [CollapsibleActionView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/CollapsibleActionView.html) and it has methods `onActionViewCollapsed` and `onActionViewExpanded()`. You may need to override these methods, like this:

```
class MySearchView extends SearchView {

         public MySearchView(Context context) {
             super(context);
         }

         @Override
         public void onActionViewExpanded() {
             super.onActionViewExpanded();
         }

         @Override
         public void onActionViewCollapsed() {
             super.onActionViewCollapsed();
         }
     }
```

Comment: I have read `SearchView.OnCloseListener` in API docs and assumed it's only called at collapse events. I tried to implements `SearchView.OnCloseListener` after see this answer, and it has no business with expand events indeed. Thanks for reply, anyway.

Comment: I asked for *both* expand/collapse events. The word *both* in title was added just now, but the original title contains *expand/collapse*, if  the "/" misled you to *either* instead of *both*, I'm really sorry for my unclear indication T_T